# Change the default "Name" column in a Form Library

Tags: infopath, column, form, forms-library, display-name

Is it possible to change the default "Name" column that is created in a form library.

One method I saw is creating a content type that inherits from this column. Could someone provide instructions on this method if it is feasable. (Details Please!)

Comment: Are you looking to do this as a one off, or do you want to do this for all forms libraries going forward?

Comment: Both. Its undetermined